# stack pointer and segmentation

Tags: assembly, operating-system, stack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does a stack memory increase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211600/how-does-a-stack-memory-increase)

let's think of an OS using segmentation.
My question is : does the os intrecepts every changes of the stack pointer
and instanly ( or quite instanly ) allocates/deallocates space in phisical memory
or it does so using a clever strategy allocating more memory than you need when you decrement the sp , deallocating memory only when freed memory has reached a certain amount ?

I hope my quetsion is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, the answer is the following:

The operating system allocates a certain amount of space for the stack at the beginning of the process creation. The processor automatically increments and decrements the stack pointer when stack operations occur, and the software and decrements the stack pointer to allocate space for temporary data (as in a function call). It is decremented because the stack actually grows down, and a stack overflow will occur if the pointer exceeds the given allocated space. The amount of space allocated differs from system to system. The only possible "tricks" the operating system can do is with paging, where it can mark the memory as allocated but will not actually allocate the physical memory until the software uses it. This is called demand paging, and has more application with the heap rather than the stack.

Comment: Also to add ..   every process has its own address space which includes a stack. The attributes which explain the process in a system has a stack pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Also to add to the above answer..
 The stack of a process grows down towards the heap , the OS has to make sure that these areas dont overlap.
When the stack needs more space(i.e stack pointer points to an illegal/unallocated memory) it results in a page fault.

1. The interupt hanlders for page fault are written such that it reads the current stack pointer , its max limits to find if the page fault happened because of stack growth or  because we touched a part of virtual memory(belonging to code/data) that is not yet mapped to physical memory(Demand paging).
2. If the page fault happened because of stack growth

   - We check to see if the max size of stack is reached it is 8Mb (default) on GNu/Linux system
   - Next we see if by allocating a new page to stack if it will overlap with heap
   - This may be followed by some more sanity checks.
   - If all the above pass then a new page is allocated
   - If one of the check fails ,there will be seg fault or stack overflow depending on implementations.
3. If we did allocate a new page in the previous step,then the stack pointer of the faulting process is updated ,new mappings are added to the page table of the faulting process and the page fault handler returns control to the faulting instruction,usually a push or pusha(in assembly, x86).

P.S: The above steps are from OS assignments of my UG OS course based on pintos OS, the actual steps may vary (be complicated in a OS S like linux).Heres the [link](http://www.cse.iitd.ac.in/~sbansal/csl373/pintos/doc/pintos_4.html) to to part of stack growth see section 4.3.3.

Comment: Thanks for the answers , you are all talking about paging but in my understanding segmentation is not the same as paging. Take a look at this link : http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSFEP/vm-segmentation.pdf

Comment: well segmentation and paging are 2 different ways to provide virtual memory to the process, infact both can co-exist.On linux paging is preffered over segmentation.

Comment: There could be a system where address space of a process segmented and then each of this segments are composed of pages. So the virtual to physical address translations has to go through 1 more level of indirection where you check the segment base:offset and limit, the idea of checking that I have mentioned remain the same. In linux the user code & data points to 1 segment,kernel code & data point to 1 segment,the base address of this segments depending on the current mode(user/kerenl) is loaded in the cs:segmentation register,address of all segment are stored in GDT (global descriptor table).