# What happens when we write int x; and return from the main function in C language does OS allocate memory for it?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I just wanted to know if declaring a variable as mentioned above is a system call to the Kernel?Because I have read that Kernel is only responsible when memory is being allocated dynamically if it is not a system call then how memory gets allocated for it,is os responsible for this memory allocation?

Comment: Of course there is memory allocated for `x` during `main`. But it's not allocated via a call to a kernal function, but it's usually allocated on the stack. Before the `main` function is executed, the does a lot of things, amoungst them it allocates memory for the stack. But the question is really too broad.

Comment: All memory used by your process is allocated and deallocated by the OS. Otherwise programs would easily cause haywire on your computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a stack memory increase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211600/how-does-a-stack-memory-increase).  The `int x` will either be put in a register or stored on the stack (automatic variable).

Answer (score 3):

> is a system call to the Kernel?

No. There is no call to the kernel.

If your variable has static storage duration, the memory for it will be allocated by the OS during the program load. The size of the area where static storage duration objects are located is known build time.

If it has automatic storage duration it will be allocated in most modern implementations on the stack during the program execution.

But both variables can be optimized out by the **compiler** if they are not needed to produce the required observable program behaviour.

If they are optimized out - no memory will be allocated for them.